# Creating Reusable Helper Functions in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been building React components for my latest app. I know I can reuse components which has helped keep my code DRY.

I wanted to know if I could reuse functions. I know there has to be a way.

Right now I have three components using a password validation function.

```
passwordValidation() {
  const length = this.state.password.length;
  if (length > 7) return 'success';
  else if (length > 4) return 'warning';
  else if (length > 0) return 'error';
}
```

I created a helper file - helpers.jsx and added:

```
export function passwordValidation() {
  const length = this.state.password.length;
  if (length > 7) return 'success';
  else if (length > 4) return 'warning';
  else if (length > 0) return 'error';
}
```

I then imported it into my component

```
import { passwordValidation } from '../helpers.jsx'
```

I keep getting the error "passwordValidation is not a function" when I try binding "this" in my constructor.

If I invoke it in the input tag, I am getting "cannot read property state of undefined."

Just trying to see where I am going wrong. Everything works if I define it in my class and add `this.passwordValidation = this.passwordValidation.bind(this)`.

I'll go back to what I was doing if this isn't best practice, but I'm under the assumption that I should be able to import functions to make life easier and my code cleaner!

Comment: Can you add the part where you tried to bind but got an error please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Helper functions should not depend on the context of the component they are called to *(at least in my opinion)*. If you need to use some parameter in your function passing that to function is always a better practice since it helps on re-usability. The key for the state property might be different for all components and this might lead to errors if you forget to use exact key for the state property.

**For Example**

```
export function passwordValidation(password) {
  const length = password.length;
  if (length > 7) return 'success';
  else if (length > 4) return 'warning';
  else if (length > 0) return 'error';
}
```

If I change function like above I can use all the given examples below.

```
import { passwordValidation } from '/path/to/helper/functions.js';

console.log(passwordValidation(this.state.password));
console.log(passwordValidation(this.state.confirmPassword));
console.log(passwordValidation(this.props.password));
console.log(passwordValidation(someFetchedObject.user.password));
```

Comment: This worked. Dumb mistake on my part copying the method directly to a helper with "this.state.password.length" and not making it universal.

Answer (score 3):

Your import and export are fine. Your using named exports/import from ES6.

The issue is trying to use state, I believe. Is there any way you can merge the three components using the password validation into one? Or remove the state reference in the helper function and just pass the password as a argument? That should work just fine.

Comment: That wound up being the issue!

Answer (score 2):

```
import { passwordValidation } from '../helpers.jsx'
```

essentially says:

```
var { passwordValidation } = (function passwordValidation () {...});
```

`passwordValidation` is a function, and functions are objects in JS, so it's essentially looking for:

```
var passwordValidation = (function...(){...}).passwordValidation;
```

Instead, just assign the function directly to `passwordValidation`:

```
import passwordValidation from '../helpers.jsx'
```

or call `require` directly if you're in a context where `require` is available.

```
const passwordValidation = require('...resource...')
```